# Drop down list not populating (PHP/Myadmin)

Tags: php, dropdownbox

I am trying to get a dropdown list to populate. I have two tables, a registration table and a studentclasses table. I am looking to populate the dropdown list from the class table, as a field entry in the registration table. My code is as follows:

```
    <p>Class: <select name="classID">
        <?php $classlist_sql="SELECT * FROM studentclasses";
            $classlist_qry=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $classlist_sql);
            $classlist_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($classlist_qry);
            do { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $classlist_rs['classID']; ?>"
                <?php 
                    if($classlist_rs['classID']==$_SESSION['signuptest']['classID']) {
                        echo "selected=selected";
                    }
                ?>
                ><?php echo $classlist_rs['classcode']; ?></option>
            <?php } while ($classlist_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($classlist_qry));
    ?></select>
</p>
```

My Studentclasses table has the fields classID and classcode, and I am wanting the classcode to appear in the drop down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any error on your code! just there is no need to do `echo "selected=selected";` replace it with `echo "  selected";`

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: What are you getting in the dropdown?

Comment: Not solution, just note: with foreach you'll write `$classlist_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($classlist_qry)` only once.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your responses. I am getting the dropdown box, but it is just not populating - its blank!